# Are hand grenades the same as the ammunition for grenade launchers?

Tags: warhammer-40k, only-war

In Only War, do grenade launchers use the same grenades as the ones you can use as hand grenades?
What about the auxiliary grenade launcher / underslung GL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the core Only War rule book there is the following sentence prefacing the table of explosives:

> The explosives listed here can either be thrown by hand or loaded in a grenade launcher as grenades, used in missile launchers as missiles, or fired from mortars as rounds.

Additionally, the grenade launcher has the following bit of description:

> The standard grenade launcher uses compressed gas charges to launch a variety of grenade types at the enemy.

Together, these lead me to believe that hand grenades and grenade launcher ammunition are in fact the same.

Comment: But explosives doesn't mean grenades. A fragmentation missile and a fragmentation grenade might use the same basic explosive but that doesn't make them the same thing. Just because the rules say that the mechanical effect of the explosion of a hand grenade and a grenade from a grenade launcher is the same doesn't mean you can jam a hand grenade in a launcher and expect it to work.

Comment: Sorry, I only saw your comment now.
While I agree in the real world, this is about a rulebook which seemingly makes no distinction between hand grenades and GL grenades. Do you have any better sources than what I quoted? 
Like I said, the quotes I found seem to support my view, even though I'd agree that it _should_ be wrong.